# C++ Drawing with BitBlt

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, draw

I have a function for a game I'm working on:

```
void DrawMap()
{
BITMAP bm;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HBITMAP sprites = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_COLOR_SPRITES));
HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, sprites);
GetObject(sprites, sizeof(bm), &bm);

// Find x and y coordinate for the top left of the visible screen
int x = 4, y = 4, ypos = 0;

// Draw lower layer
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        BitBlt(hdc, (i * 32) + 36, (j * 32) + 36, 32, 32, hdcMem, game.get_pos(game.Layer_One[x + i][y + j], ypos), ypos, SRCCOPY);

// Draw upper layer
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        if (game.Layer_One[x + i][y + j] != 0)
            BitBlt(hdc, (i * 32) + 36, (j * 32) + 36, 32, 32, hdcMem, game.get_pos(game.Layer_One[x + i][y + j], ypos, true), ypos, SRCCOPY);

SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
DeleteDC(hdcMem);
EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
}
```

The variable 'game' is an instance of a class I made to hold all the game vars and funcs.  Basically what the two grouped for loops are supposed to do is create a double-layered, 9 by 9 grid of 32 by 32 pixel tiles, which are copied from an image which has all of the tiles in one place.  I have tested my get_pos() function and it is returning the right x and y position for the partial bitmap within the full sprites bitmap.
The second parameter of get_pos() is by reference - so it can give a y value that way and return an x value.
For some reason, my function, although seemingly properly set-up to me (and definitely called) isn't producing any drawing on hWnd.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Also, is the line:
GetObject(sprites, sizeof(bm), &bm);
necessary?

Comment: Does it show the bitmap if you select the bitmap directly into the window DC? If so, does it still show if you select it into the memory DC and BitBlt all of it to the window DC?

Comment: Is `DrawMap()` called from a `WM_PAINT` handler, or another moment when at least part of the window has been invalidated? Otherwise, the device context built by `BeginPaint()` will have its clipping region set to the entire window, and drawing on it will have no effect.

Comment: To add on, if you need to draw on the window from elsewhere, use `GetDC` and `ReleaseDC` instead of `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint`.

Comment: Frédéric - This must be why nothing is showing.  It isn't being called from WM_PAINT.  It's actually indirectly being called from the InitInstance() function.  Is there a way to temporarily invalidate the window?  I'll look for a way until I hear from you or someone else...

Comment: Oh!  Actually Chris's suggestion worked.  It didn't draw the right tiles, but it drew tiles.  So now I just have to make it draw the right ones.

Comment: @BrianGradin, I love that feeling of when **something** shows up after doing all the work for something to show up and nothing happening.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't directly answer your question, but if you don't need compatibility with very old versions of windows, why not use Direct2D? GDI is very much deprecated (not to mention slow).

Comment: -1: GDI is neither slow nor deprecated. If anything, in the context of the original question which is performing `BitBlt`s ecxlusively, GDI is likely faster. And that is not even factoring in the non-trivial cost of constructing a Direct3D device. Plus, GDI is the only way to render pixel-perfect graphics (which, again, is what the OP is apparently after). Direct2D has its uses, mainly to mix 2D-rendering with Direct3D. This, however, is not one of those cases where Direct2D offers any benefits.

Comment: Clearly the question suggests use in a game-ish context, and not just blittling something to the window one off.

Direct2D requires no mucking about with Direct3D whatsoever to do something like the above. As for GDI and deprecation -- perhaps that was a little too strong, however:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: **You** do not have to _muck about with Direct3D_, however, Direct2D has to. And constructing a Direct3D device has non-trivial cost. As for the article you linked to, looking through all the evangelism you'll find the following: "BitBlt API was hardware accelerated". As for "game-ish": I don't automatically read "state of the art 3D rendering with all the bells and whistles and more" into that.

Comment: Fair enough; I suggested it only to discourage the poster from investing too much time into a legacy API (for games at least). Direct2D at least avoids the complexity of a fully 3D api like opengl or Direct3D. I believe its stated purpose is or was to replace GDI usage in new applications.